# Weak reference being nullified

Tags: android, weak-references, android-cursor

I'm using a weak reference inside a static Handler to avoid memory leaks, however, sometimes this reference is being nullified, I cannot understand why.

The static handler is defined inside a repository class that has a method to perform an operation in the background, receives a callback to notify the caller when it's done:

```
public class MyRepository {

    public void performOperation(ContentResolver cr, RepositoryCallback callback) {
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler(cr, callback);
        handler.startQuery(...)
    }

    interface RepositoryCallback {
        void onSuccess(MyModel model);
    }

    // Handler class code here
}
```

The code of the handler is the following:

```
private static class MyHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {

    private final WeakReference<RepositoryCallback> weakCallback;

    public MyHandler(ContentResolver cr, RepositoryCallback callback) {
        super(cr);
        this.weakCallback = new WeakReference<>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
        RepositoryCallback callback = this.weakCallback.get();
        if (callback != null) { // --> Here sometimes it is null
            // Do some stuff with the cursor to create MyModel
            callback.onSuccess(model);
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason, `this.weakCallback.get()` sometimes is null, and I'm trying to understand why.

The activity code looks like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void loadModel() {
        showLoadingView();
        myRepository.performOperation(context.getContentResolver(), new RepositoryCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(MyModel model) {
                hideLoadingView();
                // Do something with model
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm creating an anonymous class for the callback, but nobody is holding a reference to it.

Is this the cause of the weak reference being nullified?

Thanks.

Comment: My best guess is that GC is reclaiming it.

Comment: Yes, but why is reclaiming it? And how can I prevent that?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83 Its a good article. May be it can help you

Comment: Thanks, I read the article. Hoever, IMHO it's really short and shows a simple example. It doesn't go in depth and actually has several negative comments.

Answer (score 1):

That's the "classical" bug associated with weak references.

If the Observable holds the only reference to the Observer, and this reference is weak, then it can be cleared and Observer be garbage collected.

Since you're using anonymous class, Observable will hold the only reference to it, therefore it will be cleared.

As a side note - in my entire experience of Android development, whenever I saw devs using weak references, it always was a code smell. Usually it indicates that either devs don't understand how weak references work, or they don't trust their own code.

A good rule of thumb is that you should never use weak references.

**EDIT:**

I think that `Handler` is an anti-pattern in general. You can read more about this in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7romrl/excellent_article_on_threads_looper_handler_and/dsyn0hy/). There is also a thread there in which I helped one dev to see how he can get rid of `HandlerThread` in his codebase.

On the other hand, Jake Wharton disagreed with my statements.

Take what you'd like from there, but, in general, I would say that having a static `Handler` is anti-pattern for sure.

If you are worried about AndroidStudion warnings, then just remember that Google are responsible for `AsyncTask` and `Loaders`. This warning is not just useless, but actually bad. They should've made it `you should not use static Hadlers`.

If all you need is to offload work to BG thread and then get a callback on UI thread then you would be much better off with something like RxJava. Or even the evil `AsyncTask`.

I guess you're using `AsyncQueryHandler` in order to access `ContentProvider`. This is too a very controversial approach. If you don't need to share data with other apps, you might be better off by using some ORM that handles the multithreading for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I'm not sure about the statement "you should never use weak references", actually the Android Studio IDE suggests exactly to use a weak reference if you create a non static inner class that extends a Handler. It marks the class with a warning if you don't define it as static.

Comment: By the way, what would you do in this case? What I'm trying to achieve is to wrap the AsyncQueryHandler in a Repository class. This is because, I have other Repository implementations that also perform operations in the background and need a callback. In this example, I need to use AsyncQueryHandler, but others will use API services for example.

Comment: Thanks and yes, for now, I end up using RxJava to offload the `contentResolver.query` operation (read device photos) to a background thread, instead of using the `AsyncQueryHandler`. However, I was wondering how this could be done using just the Android framework without external libraries such as RxJava.

Comment: Well, you could just use `Threads` and `ThreadPools` directly. Or you could wrap them in some way. However, IMHO, you should only use these approaches if you really understand concurrency. For example, this is how I do it: https://github.com/techyourchance/thread-poster/blob/master/threadposter/src/main/java/com/techyourchance/threadposter/BackgroundThreadPoster.java